# Line Graph - not showing

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a problem on understanding how the d3.svg.line() command works, if it needs to be combined with path or not.
I've been trying to draw a line graph using a csv made of two columns (day, temperature)
with numeric values, but I cannot understand why the code doesn't show anything.

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UjhjY/

```
var line = svg.selectAll("line")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")
                    .interpolate("linear")
                    .x(function (i) { return xScale(i); })
                    .y(function (d) { return yScale(d[1]); });

        var path = svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", line(dataset))
            .attr("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("fill", "none");
```

While working on the code the browser doesn't show anything other than the svg file. And I am pretty clueless about what to do now. Any help and explaining would be really appreciated, since I read almost everything I could find about line and path but couldn't make it work.

Comment: please give data set which one using

Comment: yea sorry i totally forgot! i'll edit the jsfiddle link right now

EDIT: done, it's linked in the external resources on the fiddle!

Comment: also give required output image/idea

Comment: a simple line chart, like this one http://www.janwillemtulp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Line-chart.png 
for now it doesn't have the axis coded because i first wanted to see if i could make the line work

Comment: Because a lot of things has changed, use https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 as an example (2017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. First, [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) is an asynchronous callback and you can't use it like `var dataset = d3.csv("line_graph.csv");`. The second argument it takes is a function that has access to the data. The code needs to look like this.

```
d3.csv("file.csv", function(error, data) {
  // create graph
});
```

You probably also want to convert the data parsed out of the CSV from strings to whatever the actual data format is, e.g. for numbers

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.temperature = +d.temperature;
});
```

When setting up your scales, make sure that you reference the correct parts of the data. you probably want something like

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d.temperature; })])
    .range([0, height]);
```

instead of returning `d[1]`.

Then, to create the line, you need a [line generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line). This would be set up like this.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.temperature); });
```

You can then use the line generator like so to create the path.

```
svg.selectAll("path").data(data)
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("d", line);
```

These are just the most obvious problems that struck me. Here is an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) that is quite close to what you're looking for. I would strongly suggest going over a few tutorials and examples.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I see the problems on my code, I added the var dataset to have a variable responding to the dataset in the x and y Scale, like:
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
               .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
               .range([0, width]);
I don't know how to deal with this otherwise

Comment: Did you have a look at the example? You should be able to use it almost unmodified for your purposes.

Comment: i did, sorry for being a nuisance and thanks for that, it's like what i'm trying to do; but i just wanted to understand the problem in my code, or how to refer to the external dataset inside the callback

Comment: There are quite a few problems in your code -- I think it would be much easier for you to start from that example and modify as you go along.

Comment: my problem is that i do not understand some of the basics, as the little i learned of d3 is by myself and without having a background as a coder, and that example is a little too complicated for me; but i'll try from scratch again. thanks anyway